# Custom Grid Filters in ExtJS 6

Tags: javascript, extjs

In `ExtJS 4.X` there was a nice library feature called `Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature` and there was a nice [example](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/extjs-build/examples/grid-filtering/grid-filter-local.html). But I cannot find anything similar to that in `ExtJS 6`. So, my question is whether there exists such a feature in modern `ExtJS` or not. And if it exists, how can we use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'r looking for the [`gridfilters`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2-classic/Ext.grid.filters.Filters.html) plugin:

> This class is a grid plugin that adds a simple and flexible
>   presentation for store filters.
>
> Filters can be modified by the end-user using the grid's column header
>   menu. Through this menu users can configure, enable, and disable
>   filters for each column.

Comment: @CD Is there any way to retrieve the value entered in filter in my code.